# Buscar el primer código libre y eliminar un carácter en consulta mysqli

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de hacer con una consulta que me mire el primer código de barras libre que tengo pero por alguna extraña razón el resultado me da 1 y no veo donde me puedo estar equivocando.

Esta es la consulta en cuestión

```
    $CeanLibre = "SELECT min(`3`) + 1 as prox_ean_libre FROM (SELECT 0 AS `3` union all SELECT `3` FROM `Direcciones&Codigos` WHERE `3` BETWEEN '843446300001' AND '843446399999') t1 WHERE not exists (select null FROM `Direcciones&Codigos` t2 WHERE t2.`3` = t1.`3` + 1 AND t2.`3` BETWEEN '843446300001' AND '843446399999' )"; //miramos de nuevo el ultimo codigo por si aca
    $REanLibre = mysqli_query($Conectar ,$CeanLibre); //pongo un resultado de la consulta
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($Conectar));
    $DEanLibre=mysqli_fetch_array($REanLibre); 
    $EanLibre = trim($DEanLibre["prox_ean_libre"]);
```

El esquema de esa tabla es este:

```
Field   Type         Allow Null
id      int(11)         No  
que     varchar(50)     No  
idcosa  int(10) No  
1       varchar(200)    Yes 
2       varchar(200)    Yes 
3       varchar(200)    Yes 
4       varchar(200)    Yes 
5       varchar(200)    Yes 
6       varchar(200)    Yes 
7       varchar(200)    Yes 
8       varchar(200)    Yes 
9       varchar(200)    Yes 
10      text            Yes
```

En 3 tengo guardados dos códigos que serian 843446300001 y 843446300003 aunque también hay otros campos que son una dirección. Había probado a filtrar para que solo mire códigos y el resultado es el mismo así que lo he quitado intentando hacer que funcione, pero nada. Para que filtre solo códigos habria que poner que` = 'Codigo'

Por otro lado una vez funcione esto necesitare que cuando lea el código almacenado en `3` quite el ultimo numero ya que es un dígito de control y va a volver loca a la consulta. y me gustaría saber la sintaxis para poder hacerlo. Buscando por ahi he visto que es algo tipo esto: `SUBSTRING (`3`), 1, Len(`3`) - 1 )` pero no se muy bien en este caso donde tendría que ponerlo al ser una doble consulta.

Mil gracias por todo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás haciendo

```
 (SELECT 0 AS `3`... UNION ALL ...)
```

Por lo tanto el mínimo de ese conjunto es cero. Si seleccionas cero y le sumas 1, resulta 1.

**Edit**:Para quitar el último número, la consulta debe empezar con

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(min(`3`) + 1,CHAR_LENGTH(min(`3`) + 1) - 1) as prox_ean_libre FROM...
```

Pregunta: si el último número es sólo un dígito de control, qué sacas con sumarle 1 al mínimo código ocupado? A lo mejor debes quitar el dígito antes de sumar:

```
SELECT 1+SUBSTRING(min(`3`),CHAR_LENGTH(min(`3`)) - 1) as prox_ean_libre FROM...
```

Comment: Ósea que solo tengo que cambiar ese 0 por el primer código de barras

Comment: Creo que tienes que quitar esa parte del union all, después de todo la segunda parte del union all ya devolverá el primer número.

Comment: @amanadiel :) Funciona, te quiero

Comment: ¿Ya para rematar el amor absoluto no sabras a que parte le tengo que poner lo de substring? @amenadiel

Comment: Ahí edité la respuesta

Comment: Los caracteres 843446300001 son sin el digito de control que es un numero que sale de sumar los impares, luego los pares y no se que otra operación. la única variable incremental de ese  código seria los 5 últimos dígitos 00001 en el caso del ean 1 el código completo es 8434463000017. A ver si consigo hacerlo funcionar quitando el ultimo numero :) Mil gracias por todo @amenadiel